# Comparing experimental conditions using t-test

Tags: r, statistics

I have a set of experiments ran in various conditions which I'd like to compare using t-test. When I perform pairwise.t.test(mtcars$mpg, mtcars$am), my own data has the same format as mtcars, I get a p-value than a one to one t-test comparison using t.test(mtcars$mpg, mtcars$am). Is it expected? Which one should I trust?

```
t.test(mtcars$mpg, mtcars$am)

Welch Two Sample t-test
data:  mtcars$mpg and mtcars$am
t = 18.413, df = 31.425, p-value < 2.2e-16
alternative hypothesis: true difference in means is not equal to 0
95 percent confidence interval:
17.50519 21.86356
sample estimates:
mean of x mean of y 
20.09062   0.40625 

pairwise.t.test(mtcars$mpg, mtcars$am)$p.value
        0
1 0.0002850207
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Study the documentation. `t.test` expects the values of each group as the first two arguments. `pairwise.t.test` expects the values of both groups as the first argument and a grouping factor as the second argument. Furthermore, they have different defaults regarding pooling of the variance.

```
t.test(mtcars$mpg, mtcars$am)$p.value
#[1] 2.151228e-18

library(reshape2)
DF <- melt(mtcars[, c("mpg", "am")])
pairwise.t.test(DF$value, DF$variable, pool.sd = FALSE)$p.value
#            mpg
#am 2.151228e-18
```

Comment: In my exemple, we are willing to compare mpg values in both am=0 and am=1 sets which can be done, I guess, either with t.test(mtcars$mpg~mtcars$am) or with t.test(mtcars[which(mtcars$am==0),]$mpg, mtcars[which(mtcars$am==1),]$mpg). Results are the same. Because in my data (not shown) I'd like to compare more than just two sets, I thought about using pairwise.t.test instead. pairwise.t.test(mtcars$mpg, mtcars$am, pool.sd = FALSE)$p.value returns the correct value. Thanks for your help.